# PHP login access doesn't working in web server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, authentication

I am making a login system. But, I don't know whats the problem. When I checked by the right email and password or wrong email and password it show my error message `Please enter valid Email/Password!!` . I am using Php 7.1.7 . Also when I add wrong db username, password and table it doesn't show any error.
My Php code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db4245454', 'missed$', 'db424545444');

$query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = 'support@admin.com' AND password = 'Rml2ZXJyMSQ='";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$num_log = $result->num_rows;


if($num_log == 1){

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo "Welcome " .   $row->First_Name . ' '. $row->Last_Name;

        }                               
}else{

    echo "Please enter valid Email/Password!!";
}
```

My database table structure:
[image]

Comment: Please don't use this code in production..

Comment: Your database table screenshoot seems to have not uploaded completely. Could you please re-upload it?

Comment: @shrmn check now. I upload my database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is okey problem should be here in your query, maybe you gived data with is not availble in database so num_rows >=0  and != 1

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = 'support@admin.com' AND password = 'Rml2ZXJyMSQ='";
```

you can use var_dump($result); then die() to see if you got anything from database

PS never use code like this

Comment: just before your IF give var_dump($result); die();  and see if something show up on your site

Comment: so you got it :) PROBLEM is your QUERY :), your QUERY result no match any  data from your database :), i can help but you need post your DATABASE DATA info because this screenshot whot you gived us is for nothing :)

Comment: Oh.  When was working on locally there was no problem. But, now I am working on web server , create the problem.

Comment: And my query data is 100% match in my database.

Comment: nop i m 100% sure problem is your QUERY or your data in database because RESULT is NULL so in your database there is no data with Email = 'support@admin.com' AND password = 'Rml2ZXJyMSQ='

Comment: Ok. Just a minute. I check again.

Comment: also you can try mysqli_connect(), because new mysqli is not perfect

`$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);`

Comment: I added my email and pw from my database it is not working

Comment: so maybe you connecting to wrong database but your CODE is 100% Okey problem is on your SIDE ( QUERY / DABASE DATA / CONNECTED TO DATABASE 2 where is 0 DATA like your QUERY ) 

tested on my own database and it works PERFECT

Comment: use this $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db); and also var_dumb($mysqli);

Comment: `<?php

$host = "mysql.example.com";
$user = "user_name";
$pass = "user_pass";
$db = "db_name"

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = 'support@admin.com' AND password = 'Rml2ZXJyMSQ='");


if($$result->num_rows == 1){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo "Welcome " .   $row->First_Name . ' '. $row->Last_Name;
        }                               
}else{
    echo "Please enter valid Email/Password!!";
}  `

Comment: i hope this is just joke my real host for database is : 46.229.230.242  for example  name for example : "ejsdsad554" datbaseName: "db68412" just for example

all info you get from your HOSTING company so IP or localhost for localhost

Comment: so problem is your PC / your CONFIGURATION for local server , install XAMP and run MySQL and Apach  move your project into it and it should works if not reinstall your PC and do it again until it will wokrs, there is no way to help you with installing programs you should watch youtube tutorials how to install XAMP or MySQL on PC

Comment: I have installed XAMPP in my PC.

Comment: but looks like wrong or maybe you use wrong info about your MySQL server HOST = localhost, USER = root, PASS = , DBNAME = your db name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159039/discussion-between-acoder-and-patrik-horvath).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the right way to go. The simplest is to add a "Role" column and determine if the client is "admin", "customer" or any other level that you want to have, so you can manage multiple admin with each own access.
For the code it will be enough for you to check what is the "Role" of your client and to display the corresponding message / page.

```
            <?php
            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db4245454', 'missed$', 'db424545444');

            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                printf("Echec de la connexion: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }

            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = 'support@admin.com' AND password = 'Rml2ZXJyMSQ='");
            $row = $result->num_rows;

            if($row == 1){


                        echo "Welcome " .   $row->First_Name . ' '. $row->Last_Name;


            }else{

                echo "Please enter valid Email/Password!!";
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: I think the problem in my db_user and db_pass .

Comment: This is the good method : $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");